# TinyMCE Event after template is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCEv4 and using it as a body editor for my email popup like Gmail. I would like to add the title of the template applied to the subject line of the email popup.

Eg- If we select the Agree template -
[image]

so we should be able to see the title of the template in the subject line -
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I have used the `BeforeSetContent` event of TinyMce [BeforeSetContent](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/#beforesetcontent) and append the Template name to subject line.

```
tinymce.get('emailBodyDiv').on('BeforeSetContent', function (e) {
let selectedTemplateTitle;

 $('[role="presentation"][type="button"]').each(function (i, obj) {
    if (obj.getAttribute("id").includes('mceu_') && obj.getAttribute("id").includes('-open'))
        selectedTemplateTitle = $(obj).find(".mce-txt").text();
});

$('#emailSubjectBox').val(selectedTemplateTitle);});
```

Comment: you could replace the each with selectedTemplateTitle=$("button[id^=mceu_][id$=-open]").find(".mce-txt").text();